# typoscript using page id in config.htmlTag_setParams string

Tags: typo3, typoscript, manifest.cache

My problem is, that i cant get the TSFE:id into the config.htmlTag_setParams

```
manifest = TEXT 
manifest.value = manifest="/cache.manifest?uid={TSFE:id}"
manifest.insertData = 1

config.htmlTag_setParams < manifest
```

can anyone give me a clue, i tried everything and cant get it to work, is it even possible?
or is there any other way?

```
config.htmlTag_setParams.data = TSFE:id
config.htmlTag_setParams.wrap = manifest="/cache.manifest?uid=|"
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [TSref](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html) **config.htmlTag_setParams** is string, so no stdWrap can be applied here, but there is an option **config.htmlTag_stdWrap**, which you can use (from TYPO3 4.7) in desired way:

```
config.htmlTag_stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
config.htmlTag_stdWrap.cObject.data = TSFE:id
config.htmlTag_stdWrap.cObject.wrap = <html manifest="/cache.manifest?uid=|" >
```

NOTE: I didn't test an example above, so, please, check if it works. If not - check this [ticket](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/30404) for more advanced html tag override.